# javascript in a html file works fine in my live server using VS Code but if i open the .html file locally it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

The code basically is for making a Quiz. I'm using quiz maker and copied the code that they gave me and altered it a bit. But the thing is, it works fine if I launch it in Vs code using live server. However if I open the file(.html file) from the folder nothing works. Also I have this error on local "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND".

```
    <script>
      (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
        var ql = document.querySelectorAll('A[quiz],DIV[quiz],A[data-quiz],DIV[data-quiz]');
        if (ql) {
          if (ql.length) {
            for (var k = 0; k < ql.length; k++) {
              ql[k].id = 'quiz-embed-' + k;
              ql[k].href =
                "javascript:var i=document.getElementById('quiz-embed-" +
                k +
                "');try{qz.startQuiz(i)}catch(e){i.start=1;i.style.cursor='wait';i.style.opacity='0.5'};void(0);";
            }
          }
        }
        i['QP'] = r;
        (i[r] =
          i[r] ||
          function () {
            (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments);
          }),
          (i[r].l = 1 * new Date());
        (a = s.createElement(o)), (m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]);
        a.async = 1;
        a.src = g;
        m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m);
      })(window, document, 'script', '//cdn.poll-maker.com/quiz-embed-v1.js', 'qp');
    </script>
    <script>
      function closeBanner() {
        const trial = document.querySelector('.trial-box');
        trial.style.display = 'none';
      }
    </script>
```

```html
<a
      onclick="closeBanner()"
      data-quiz="Q81HSFC7B"
      data-type="5"
      data-fullscreen="true"
      href="https://www.quiz-maker.com/Q81HSFC7B"
      style="
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: left;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 824px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 1em;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        color: inherit;
      "
      ><div
        style="
          display: block;
          font-family: sans-serif;
          font-size: 1.5em;
          line-height: 40px;
          color: inherit;
        "
      >
        English Assessment Exam
      </div></a
    >
```

Answer (score 2):

`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`  means that some resource attached in your html doesn't exist.

Instead of `//cdn.poll-maker.com/quiz-embed-v1.js`, just replace it to `https://cdn.poll-maker.com/quiz-embed-v1.js`

Comment: i tried it and it helped but got a new error "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file://www.quiz-maker.com/qapi/Take%2081HSFC7B&tt=1599615131857' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https."

Comment: "file://www.quiz-maker.com/qapi/Take%2081HSFC7B&tt=1599615131857" means it's accessing your computer's file:// directory and not from the internet.. Just find the link in your html code then replace file:// to https:// in order to make it work.

Comment: When you open your file in a browser directly from disk it has a `file:` url protocol. If you then resolve a protocol-less url against it, like `//cdn.poll-maker.com/quiz-embed-v1.js`, you end up with `file://cdn.poll-maker.com/...`, which doesn’t exist unless you happen to have the file at that location on your local drive. Running a local http server instead of opening the file will eliminate many of these kinds of problems.